# mysql multiple OR NOT LIKES

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a wordpress plugin that essentially creates a mysql query and returns the results to wordpress.

It is user driven and so can end up in large queries with multiple NOT LIKEs which results in a very slow query.

Any suggestions that I could use to improve:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 
from datatable 
WHERE (title NOT LIKE '%word%' AND title NOT LIKE '%word2%'
AND title NOT LIKE '%word3%' AND title NOT LIKE '%word4%' 
AND title NOT LIKE '%word5%' AND title NOT LIKE '%word6%' 
AND title NOT LIKE '%word7%' AND title NOT LIKE '%word8%' 
AND title NOT LIKE '%word9%') 
AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ("\"brandname\" " IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY total ASC LIMIT 0,60
```

The customer is adding a lot of negative keywords to the wordpress plugin which results in larger queries than the one above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most easily done with [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).  For multiple words, use a group like `(one|two|three)`

```
SELECT 
  field1,
  field2,
  field3,
  field4
from datatable
WHERE 
  title NOT REGEXP '(word1|word2|word3|word4|word5...|word9)'
  AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ("\"brandname\" " IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY total ASC
LIMIT 0,60
```

Comment: excellent, I'll give it a try, Will that improve query speed do you think?

Comment: @user1237700 It will probably speed it up a little, only way to know is to test it and benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operation to compare all the patterns at once.

Your query will be something like:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 
  FROM data table
 WHERE title NOT REGEXP '^word[0-9]?$'
   AND MATCH(title) ("\"brandname\" " IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER BY total ASC LIMIT 0,60
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, how would I do that with multiple words please?

Comment: That's all you need for all your words. Try the query. The regular expression will match `word`, `word1`, `word2`, `word3`, `word4`, `word5`, `word6`, `word7`, `word8` and `word9`.

Comment: sorry! word & word1 & word2 aren't actually like that they can be anything the user enters.   I think Michael has explained it above word1 | word2 | etc with | seperator